# Python - Transfer a file between two remote servers, excecuting a python script

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to copy a file between two servers from a `localServer`, say from `server-A` to `server-B`. I am using paramiko package in python.

So there are three servers namely, `localServer`, `server-A` and `server-B`. Please see the below code, this is self explanatory and please let me know where I am going wrong.

Algorithm I am using:

1. I am trying to run `paramiko_test.py` file from `localServer`.
2. `paramiko_test.py` executes `copy.py` file in `server-A`.
3. `copy.py` copies file `source.txt` file in `server-A` to `server-B` using SFTP.

When I run `copy.py` from `server-A`, it is working correct. But when I run `paramiko_test.py` from `localServer` (which indirectly executes `copy.py` in `server-A`), it is not working!

From logs, I got to know that there is a successful connection from `server-A` to `server-B`, but after that the SFTP part is not working!

**Question:** Can we invoke a SFTP client within a SFTP client? Is there any better way to copy files between two servers?

Please help me where I am going wrong.

**server-A, file:copy.py:**

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('<server-B-IP>', username='serverB', password='passwd')

print "connected successfully!"

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
print sftp
sftp.put('source.txt','/home/serverB/destination.txt' )
sftp.close()
print "copied successfully!"

ssh1.close()
exit()
```

**localServer, paramiko_test.py:**

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('<server-A-IP>', username='serverA', password='passwd')

print "connected successfully!"

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("python /home/username/copy.py")

print stdout.readlines()

print "copied successfully!"

ssh.close()
exit()
```

The output of `stderr.readlines()` is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/sitaram/sumanth/test_progs/copy.py", line 12, in <module>
 sftp1.put('./sumanth_temp.txt','/home/ncloudadmin/sumanth.txt' ) 
 File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 558, in put
 file_size = os.stat(localpath).st_size
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './sumanth_temp.txt'
```

Comment: Have you looked at Fabric? It's a bit easier than Paramiko to [work with files](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/contrib/files.html) and can do things like [put a file on a remote server](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put)

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply. I looked at Fabric, I didnt see anywhere Fabric supporting file transfer between two remote hosts, running script in another local Server. Or is it supported by Fabric?? Please help.

Comment: Can you SSH into one of the remote servers, and then SFTP/SCP across? Are you getting anything in your `sterr`?

Comment: The output of - `print stderr.readlines()` is 
`['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', `
`'  File "/home/username/copy.py", line 12, in <module>\n', `
`"    sftp1.put('./source.txt','/home/serverB/dest_file.txt' ) \n", `
`'  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 558, in put\n', `
`'    file_size = os.stat(localpath).st_size\n', `
`"OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './source.txt'\n"]`

Comment: But I see source.txt is present in the right directory!!

Comment: I am not finding any problem if I run the same copy.py file from serverA !!

Comment: I've added your output to your question. In `copy.py` could you print `os.getcwd()`? You might be running in the wrong directory, so Python can't find your file. You could also try using a full filepath - i.e. `'\user\sumanth\sumanth_temp.txt'`

Comment: hey Alex, thanks for the help :) It worked. I gave absolute path . But I still wonder why it was not working before!!!

Comment: Fabric is your best bet, run rsync command on any of the host servers using api.run()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Question is year old, so probably not relevant anymore, but maybe it will be useful to others. The problem is in your copy.py.

```
sftp.put('source.txt','/home/serverB/destination.txt' )
```

where is source.txt located? Either provide full path, or if the file is always located in in the same dir as copy.py you could modify your paramiko_test.py

```
ssh.exec_command("cd /home/username/; python /home/username/copy.py")
```

Comment: will the `sftp.put` or `sftp.get` make sure that the `ssh.exec_command` will not execute until they are done with transferring the file?