# Copy InMemory file to remote server

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to copy a file in `request.FILES` to a remote location such as `100.100.1.100/home/dbadmin/EncFiles` in Django? I have consulted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-to-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625509/python-transfer-a-file-between-two-remote-servers-excecuting-a-python-script) questions but I don't need to log on to the server to copy file.

I have a simple file in my memory that I need to send to another server. How do I do that?

Comment: I think InMemoryUploadedFile class in Django may be useful for you. Because my code context is different with yours , I can't give you the example code, but you can do try it

Comment: can you give me the code that takes a normal file so i can see if i can change that for my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be very simple in the end. I created two users on both computers with same credentials, gave rights to the folder to this user and used the following code to copy file. Oh and the computers where connected by LAN.

```
serverPath = r"\\192.111.111.111/myFolder"

if os.path.exists(serverPath):
    for key in request.FILES:
        fileName = request.FILES[key].name
        d, filePath = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=request.FILES[key].name, dir=serverPath)

        with open(filePath, 'wb') as outFile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(request.FILES[key], outFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment seems to can't have contain formated code, so I have to use answer to reply:

```
def crop_avatar(file_path,size):

    avatar_format = get_image_format(os.path.splitext(file_path)[1])
    file_format = avatar_format.split('/')[1]
    avatar_filename = get_avatar_filename(file_path)

    image_file = default_storage.open(file_path)
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    if image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
        image = image.convert('RGB')
    width,height = image.size

    crop_ratio = float(200)/(size[2]-size[0])
    ratio = float(480)/width * crop_ratio

    width  = int(width  * ratio)
    height = int(height * ratio)

    left = int(size[0] * crop_ratio)
    top =  int(size[1] * crop_ratio)

    crop_image = image.resize((width,height),Image.ANTIALIAS)


    crop_image = crop_image.crop((left,top,left+200,top+200))

    avatar_io = BytesIO()#this is for default_storage using.
    crop_image.save(avatar_io, format=file_format)

    avatar = InMemoryUploadedFile(
        avatar_io,
        None,
        avatar_filename,
        avatar_format,
        len(avatar_io.getvalue()),
        None)
    avatar.seek(0)
    saved_path =  default_storage.save(avatar_filename, avatar)
    image_file.close()
    default_storage.delete(file_path)


    return saved_path
```