# Python Module to copy files between two remotes

Tags: python-3.7

I have tried many modules like *sftp*, *paramiko*, *fabric* but I am failing in framing logic for file copy between two servers.

Scenario:

Server - A is my local linux machine, which has `copy_files_remotely.py`

Server - B is source remote which consists of `sample.txt` file

Server - C is destination remote which needs to copy `sample.txt` file to `/home/user`

How to execute `copy_files_remotely.py` which copies file from Server-B to Server-C by providing both the credentials ?

Comment: Was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625509/python-transfer-a-file-between-two-remote-servers-excecuting-a-python-script) of any help ?

Comment: Nope, as it needs a python file(copy.py) in Server -A, but that's not recommend as per our requirements